# C: on calculating the array length with the integer type pointer parameter

Tags: c

I wrote a short code which calculates mean value from an integer array. I first created a header file named `mean.h` which is as follows.

```
#ifndef MEAN_H
#define MEAN_H

double mean(int *inputs) {
    int i = 0;
    int len;

    while((inputs[i]) != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }
    len = i;

    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(inputs+i));
    }
    printf("\n");

    int sum = 0;
    printf("input length: %d\n", len);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
        sum += *(inputs+i);
    }
    double mean = sum / len;
    return mean;
}

#endif
```

Then, in order to check if the code is working fine, I created another code named `test.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mean.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int arr[5] = {94, 28, 54, 72, 89};
    double meanVal = mean(arr);

    int arrlen = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    printf("Input length: %d\n", arrlen);   
    printf("Inputs: ");
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *(arr+i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Mean: %lf\n", meanVal);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled and ran the code, it showed a really strange result like this..

```
94 28 54 72 89 32767 2123416711 352349365 1594502056 32767 -1876691539 32767 -1876691539 32767 
input length: 14
Input length: 5
Inputs: 94 28 54 72 89 
Mean: 22644032.000000
```

The first five elements were printed out with no problem, but I still cannot figure out where the other next 9 elements came from. I believe that probably it's this code snippet that's not proper.

```
while((inputs[i]) != '\0') {
        ++i;
    }
```

In this case, how should I modify this in order to calculate the array length with the pointer variable parameter?

Comment: "I believe that probably it's this code snippet that's not proper." You are right. Where exactly in your original `arr` is there a `'\0'` character?

Comment: @kaylum I thought that null indicates the end of an array. If that was a wrong approach, how should I indicate the end of an array? I already tried using NULL instead, but that turned out to be wrong, with the printed message on the console saying `comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'void *')`.

Comment: No, there is no such general rule that arrays in C are automatically terminated by any value. C strings are indeed defined to be terminated by `\0` but that is specific to strings and not arrays in general. It's up to you to decide how to mark the end of the array. You can use a sentinel value that isn't a valid data value (e.g. 0 or -1) but you need to *explicitly* set that (well, actually 0 can be implicitly set but will leave that for now). The other common idiom is to pass the array size to the function.

Comment: Also, it's very bad practice to put function definitions into header files. The headers should contain only declarations. The function definitions should go in a C file.

Comment: @kaylum Thank you for the another tip. Let me correct the code and re-post it.

Comment: change to `int arr[] = {94, 28, 54, 72, 89, 0};` to make your code work.  Or you could add the length as a second parameter to the function.

Comment: Also suggest `double mean = sum / len;` --> `double mean = 1.0*sum / len;` if you want the division to occur with FP math instead of integer math.

Answer (score 0):

[It's been pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39864875/c-on-calculating-the-array-length-with-the-integer-type-pointer-parameter#comment67017645_39864875) that C arrays are not automatically null terminated. You have to do it yourself.

Unfortunately, this technique won't work for what you're doing. In an array of integers, null is indistinguishable from 0. Your `mean` function will not be able to take the mean of anything with a 0 in it. Instead it will think the list is done.

There's alternative techniques to deal with this. First is to have the caller pass in the length of the array. This is how `main` works. `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. As you can imagine, this is inconvenient and error prone.

A better one is to use an array of floats or doubles. These allow some special values such as `INFINITY` and `NAN` (not a number). You can use `NAN` as your array terminator and [`isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan) to check for it.

```
for( i = 0; !isnan(inputs[i]); i++ ) {
    printf("%.2lf ", inputs[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Beyond that, you'd declare a struct which can remember its length.

```
struct {
    int *array;
    size_t length;
};
```

Then you'd have to remember to keep that `length` always up to date. Rather than going down that rabbit hole, it's better to use a pre-existing C library which provides this such as Gnome Lib. It provides all sorts of missing pieces for C including [arrays that remember their size and can grow automatically](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Arrays.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

double mean(GArray *nums) {
    int i = 0;

    int sum = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < nums->len; i++) {
        sum += g_array_index(nums, int, i);
    }

    return sum / nums->len;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int _nums[] = {94, 28, 54, 72, 89};
    GArray *nums = g_array_new(FALSE, FALSE, sizeof(int));
    g_array_append_vals(nums, _nums, 5);

    double meanVal = mean(nums);

    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < nums->len; i++ ) {
        printf("%d ", g_array_index(nums, int, i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Mean: %.2lf\n", meanVal);

    g_array_free(nums, TRUE);

    return 0;
}
```